# Unable to retrieve ID to update in database

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am unable to identify the mistake

model (here I am matching the id to update)

```
function get_account_record($a_id)
{

    $this->db->where('a_id', $a_id);
    $this->db->from('account_info');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

controller (receiving everything via post accept the ID i-e a_id )

```
function update($a_id)
{
    $data['a_id'] = $a_id;
    $data['view'] = $this->sf_model->get_account_record($a_id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_name', 'Account Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_only_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_web', 'Website', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

form Validation

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('viewUpdate', $data);
}
else {
    $data = array(

        'a_name' => $this->input->post('a_name'),
        'a_website' => $this->input->post('a_web'),
        'a_billingStreet' => $this->input->post('a_billingStreet'),
        'a_mobile' => $this->input->post('a_mobile'),);

    $this->db->where('a_id', $a_id);
    $this->db->update('account_info', $data);
```

display success message

```
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Successfully Updated!</div>');
        //redirect('salesforce' . $a_id);
    }

}
```

view (ID and Name)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row colbox">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
            <label for="a_id" class="control-label">Account ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <input id="a_id" name="a_id" placeholder="" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $a_id;?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_id'); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row colbox">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
            <label for="a_name" class="control-label">Account Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <input id="a_name" name="a_name" placeholder="Enter Account Name" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $view[0]->a_name; ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_name'); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting value of `$id` in `update` function

Comment: disabled input won't send the data to the server.

Comment: add hidden element to send the data   <input id="a1_id" name="a1_id"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a_id;?>" />

Comment: i removed the disabled and aaded that hidden, now em recieving the id but it still saying  Undefined variable: a_id and is not updating @Sundar

Comment: @Uchiha yup getting the value

Comment: $data['a_id'] = $a_id;
$data['view'] = $this->sf_model->get_account_record($a_id);
These 2 lines are having trouble (Undefined variable: a_id)
@Sundar

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow the user to edit then add readonly instead of disabled attribute

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
        <input id="a_id" name="a_id" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $a_id;?>" />
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_id'); ?></span>
    </div>
```

If you want to disable then add the hidden element

```
<input id="a1_id" name="a1_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a_id;?>" />
```

Controller Function

```
function update($a_id)
{
    //read the value using input library    
    $a_id  = $this->input->post('a_id');

    //$a1_id  = $this->input->post('a1_id'); your hidden element value can be get here.
    $data['a_id'] = $a_id;
    $data['view'] = $this->sf_model->get_account_record($a_id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_name', 'Account Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_only_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_web', 'Website', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
}
```

Comment: after applying readonly i am getting the value of a_id
but unable to update the DB

Comment: i am busy in my work. remaining try yourself with documentation. There is no update code related queries on this post

Comment: i have a dropdown attribute but its not showing the value from db in my ui.<?php
                            $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "a_type"';
                            echo form_dropdown('a_type',$type,set_value('a_type'),$attributes);?>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_type'); ?></span>

Answer (score 0):

> My problem Solved after editing the where clause in update query

```
$this->db->where('a_id', $_POST['a_id']);
```